# Probability: identify the sample space of sum of numbers when rolling 2 six-sided cubes

Tags: probability

I have an question from OpenStax([1](https://cnx.org/contents/mwjClAV_@6.66:Dfuyh6VB@7/Probability)):"Two six-sided number cubes are rolled.Find the probability that the sum of the numbers rolled is less than or equal to 3". 1st step is to identify sample space. The answer from the book is 36. But I think all possible sum of numbers should range from 2 to 12, which makes the sample space 11. So which one is right and why? Look forward to hearing your opinions. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the outcomes that you identify between 2 and 12, like a sum of 7, are more likely than others, like a sum of 2. There is only one way, for example, for the sum of 2 to be achieved (both dice 1). If we count the *number of ways each possible sum can be achieved*, we will get, as the book says, 36.

It can be helpful in this type of question to set up a table: a row for each outcome of one die, a column for each outcome of the second, the sum of dice outcomes in each cell.

Comment: Thank @Richard Ambler! The explanation was clear.